# sort string array in order "a A b B c C" in C

Tags: c++, c, string, sorting

Here is a little function called sort_list_forward

```
struct customer * sort_list_forward (struct customer * liste_)
{
    struct customer *pointer1, *pointer2;
    struct customer tmp;

    if (liste_!=NULL)
    {
        pointer1 = liste_;
        while(pointer1 != NULL)
        {
            pointer2 = pointer1->next;
            while(pointer2 != NULL)
            {

                if (strcmp(pointer1->name,pointer2->name) > 0)
                {
                    strcpy(tmp.name, pointer2->name);
                    strcpy(pointer2->name, pointer1->name);
                    strcpy(pointer1->name, tmp.name);
                }
                pointer2 = pointer2->next;
            }
            pointer1 = pointer1->next;
        }
        return liste_;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("sortnames: no elements avaiable");
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

The struct customer looks like

```
typedef struct customer {
    char name[256];
    struct customer *next;
    struct customer *previous;
};
```

and if I use this function the output looks like

```
Ann
Bernd
Hans
barbara
bart
berta
homer
```

but I want an output that looks like

```
Ann
barbara
bart
berta
Bernd
homer
Hans
```

a A b B c C d D ...

I searched for more than 8 hours but found nothing :(

Comment: This would be so much easier if you used `std::string` and `std::sort`.

Comment: Is this C or C++? I suspect it is C.

Comment: You can rather easily implement your own version of `strcmp` based on your comparison criteria. Use the standard `strcmp` as reference, it's free

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `strcmp`, compare your strings using collation order, by calling `strcoll`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `strcasecmp` as the sort order is to ignore the case of the words.

Comment: `strcasecmp` is not part of the C or C++ standards. It's POSIX.

Comment: If I use strcasecmp the output looks like, 
Ann
barbara
bart
Bernd
berta
Hans
homer